# Continuity of the complex natural log

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to understand the continuity of the principal branch of $\log(z)$. Since $\log|z|$ is already continuous, it is sufficient to show that $\text{Arg} \colon \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z \in \mathbb{R}:z \le 0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $z \mapsto \text{Arg}(z)$ is continuous as well. The idea my professor mentioned was to pick a convergent sequence $\{z_n\}$ and show that its image under $\text{Arg}$ is still convergent. Her argument goes as follows:

> Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $z_0$ be the limit point of $\{z_n\}$. Since the set $G:= \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z \in \mathbb{R}:z \le 0\}$ is open we can find a $ 0 < \delta < \epsilon$ such that
>   $$
> \Sigma_\delta(z_0) := \{z \in G:|\text{Arg}(z) - \text{Arg}(z_0)| < \delta \} \subseteq G.
> $$
>   Now since $z_n \to z_0$ we can find a $N$ so that if $n \ge N$ we have $z_n \in \Sigma_\delta(z_0)$. This implies that for $n\ge N$ we have $|\text{Arg}(z_n) - \text{Arg}(z_0)| < \delta < \epsilon $, and $\text{Arg}(\cdot)$ preserves convergent sequences.

However, it seems to me that the line "Now since $z_n \to z_0$ we can find a $N$ so that if $n \ge N$ we have $z_n \in \Sigma_\delta(z_0)$." is precicely what we are trying to prove. What am I missing here?

Additionally, what is a good way to think about convergent sequences/continuous functions in terms of polar coordinates since the representation in this way is not unique as it is in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Yes, it's a petitio principii. You only know that $\Sigma_{\delta}(z_0)$ is open when you know that the argument is continuous. In my opinion, it's much better to derive the continuity of the argument from the continuity of the logarithm. You can define the logarithm as $$\operatorname{Log} z := \int_1^z \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta},$$ where the integral is over any curve from $0$ to $z$ in the slit plane. Then it's easy to see that the logarithm is continuous.

Comment: Or you can consider $\exp \colon \{ z : \lvert \operatorname{Im} z\rvert < \pi\} \to \mathbb{C}$ - holomorphic and injective - and define the logarithm as its inverse. Once again continuity easily follows from general principles. (Inverse function theorem of real analysis for example, or the open mapping theorem.)